# Переменная невидима из другого файла на Си

Tags: c, winapi

У меня в 3 файлах на Си:

main.c:

```
#include  "obswmcr.h"
...
BitBlt (  hdc,  0,  0,  265,  175,  memBit,  0,  0,  SRCCOPY  )
```

obswmcr.c

```
...
HDC memBit;
...
```

obswmcr.h

```
 ...
 extern  HDC memBit;
 ...
```

В CodeBlocks компилировал через Build - картинка выводилась BitBlt (), всё работало как надо.

Потом скомпилировал через Rebuild, вот вывод -

> ||=== Build: Debug in cbp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   obj\Debug\redmi\glav\rbq\glav\main.o||In function 'ProcGlavOkna@16':|
>   D:\kod\redmi\glav\rbq\glav\main.c|92|undefined reference to `memBit'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|

Что делать?

Теперь проблема решена - я определил HDC memBit; в глобальной области видимости. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что obswmcr.c не компилируется. Покажите весь вывод процесса компиляции.

Comment: форум не позволяет столько много символов за раз вывести.-------------- Build: Debug in cbp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\fayl\rbq\fayl\fayl.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\fayl\rbq\fayl\fayl.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\o\rbq\o\o.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\o\rbq\o\o.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\obswmcr\rbq\obswmcr\obswmcr.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\obswmcr\rbq\obswmcr\obswmcr.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\otkrfl\rbq\otkrfl\otkrfl.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\otkrfl\rbq\otkrfl\otkrfl.o

Comment: выложите на pastebin.com тогда, а сюда дайте ссылку

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8ravPCz7

Comment: а где конкретно у вас объявлена эта переменная HDC memBit; в файле obswmcr.c? Учтите, что она должна быть глобальной, а не локальной!

Comment: Вы правы! Ошибка была в этом. Я сделал её глобальной - и всё заработало. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, в результате обсуждения и исследования [логов сборки](http://pastebin.com/8ravPCz7), установлено:

Файлы проекта нормально компилировались

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\fayl\rbq\fayl\fayl.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\fayl\rbq\fayl\fayl.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\o\rbq\o\o.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\o\rbq\o\o.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\obswmcr\rbq\obswmcr\obswmcr.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\obswmcr\rbq\obswmcr\obswmcr.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\otkrfl\rbq\otkrfl\otkrfl.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\otkrfl\rbq\otkrfl\otkrfl.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\rabobl\rbq\rabobl\rabobl.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\rabobl\rbq\rabobl\rabobl.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\s\rbq\s\s.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\s\rbq\s\s.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\u\rbq\u\u.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\u\rbq\u\u.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\zapzav\rbq\zapzav\zapzav.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\zapzav\rbq\zapzav\zapzav.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\kod\redmi\glav\rbq\glav\main.c -o obj\Debug\redmi\glav\rbq\glav\main.o
```

Следовательно, единственная причина - переменная была локальной а не глобальной.

**ВЫВОД:**
Чтобы `extern` работал, переменную следует объявлять глобальной.

Вопрос о допустимости создания глобальных сущностей оставим за рамками.

Comment: Локальная переменная не имеет связывания. Так что вы что-то путаете.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Что и где конкретно я путаю?

Comment: Переменная имеет связывание, если она глобальная переменная. В этом случае она может иметь либо внешнее связывание либо внутреннее связывание. Переменная с автоматической памятью не имеет связывания.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow так я о том и говорю - переменную декларировали как extern в заголовке, но само объявление сделали локальным. Вот и не заработало.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что саму переменную не определили.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Именно так. Только extern HDC memBit в заголовочном файле, который включен в оба исходника. И в одном из них локальная переменная с тем же именем. А глобальной - нету.